# Xdebug establish issue

Tags: xdebug

I installed the xdebug and activated it from php.ini. Then when I debug it shows following notice:
"Connection with 'xdebug 2.5.0rc1' was not established. Validate installation"
Then after click, it shows
"Debug extension settings was updated. Please re-run current configuration to use new values."
Anyone can tell me how to re-run the configuration or how to fix this issue?

Comment: As I understand you are using PhpStorm (based on the description). What OS you are on?